# jQuery based icon picker for my own icons

Tags: jquery, icons, picker

https://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/

This is perfect icon picker for bootstrap. I want to use this icon picker but with my own icons. Not with bootstrap icons.

How can i do that, or can you give me an adress for custom icon picker
Thanks inadvance.

Comment: as I see sources at github, it contains sets of icons https://github.com/victor-valencia/bootstrap-iconpicker/tree/master/src/js/iconset, you can fork the repository, add your own set and use it

Comment: Thnaks for the answer, yes it contains some iconsets but all of iconsets are css based. I have no css based icons, i have some png format icon files

Comment: You're saying you have distinct images per icon rather than font- or sprite- based icons?

Comment: yes exactly this what i need

Comment: I think you can use jquery ui autocomplete, it can behave exactly same as you wish. It provides many parameters also, so you can render your custom html inside dropbox.

Comment: I didn't deployed it, but looked through the code, might be what you need https://github.com/balachuang/IconPicker, here is demo http://balachuang.github.io/IconPicker/

Comment: Thanks @DicBrus This is very good. I just need to implement paging system for this. Thanks again.

Comment: @MGR added as answer, maybe useful for somebody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this repository http://github.com/balachuang/IconPicker

here is [DEMO](http://alachuang.github.io/IconPicker)

Answer (score 0):

Try my new [**Universal Icon Picker**](https://github.com/migliori/universal-icon-picker) on Github

Adding new custom icon libraries is very simple:

1. Upload your icon font or Create it with for instance [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/)
2. Create a JSON file with your icon list
3. Instanciate the icon picker with your icon library

Here's the online demo: https://www.universal-icon-picker.miglisoft.com

Note: it's not a jQuery plugin, but a Vanilla js plugin, but I assume this should not be a problem.